# deducing the name of the variable from positional parameters in a posix shell

Tags: shell, posix, sh

```
#!/bin/sh
foo()
{
  printf "$1"
}
RANDOM_VAR="hello\n"
foo $RANDOM_VAR
```

When you pass 1 or more variables to a function, in this case `foo`, they are accessible through `$1` `$2` and so on; how do you go a step back from inside `foo` and print the name of the original variable which in this case means `RANDOM_VAR` ?

Comment: Succinctly, you don't or can't.  There's no guarantee that the argument is a variable, or a single variable: `foo 123` and `foo ${HOME}:${PATH}` illustrate each of these alternatives.

Comment: Besides what is being passed to function is just the value. Name of the variable isn't even passed to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Succinctly, you don't or can't tell from inside the function which variables were used to create the argument to the function.  There's no guarantee that the argument is a variable, or a single variable — for example:

```
foo 123
foo ${HOME}:${PATH}
```

Further, if the function cares, it is probably mis-written.  It should be as nearly self-contained as possible, and therefore independent of such issues.  If it isn't, it suggests that maybe the function is not functionally cohesive.

Comment: I was aware of that, meaning that I know that in a shell a variable can be seen as a function and viceversa simply because there is no real distinction between the 2, I was hoping for some kind of tracing, like having an ID or an address for a variable and print the name associated with that address .

Comment: Nothing doing in a POSIX shell.  You might be able to find something out in Bash, but I'm not remotely confident of that, either.